# Camera - follow path and change rotation

Tags: animation, camera, path

I created the camera moving by the curve using parenting and follow path option. However, how to do so that the camera moves on this curve, simultaneously changing the rotation so that all the time it  observes the other object (moving along a second path beside)? I have tried to add "track to" option, but the camera was adjusted completely not in this direction what it is necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to do it.

1. Create 2 curve paths, create a camera and a target object and parent each to one curve (<kbd>CTRL-P</kbd>, then Follow Path).
2. Add a Track To constraint to the Camera with the target object set as the target
3. Set the appropriate axis on the Track To constraint so that the camera points at the target. You may need to apply scale and rotation on the camera and/or target object to get it to work.
4. The camera's rotation will match the target object. You may need to rotate the target object to get the camera Z axis pointing up. Starting with **-Z** for **To Axis** and **Y** for the **Up Axis** will get you where you want to be most of the time.

[image]

Comment: thanks for this tip. looks almost like what I want to have. what has to be selected before hitting ctrl+p and how to select the parent? how to define a second path to follow afterwards? or do I have to extend the path? how to define how fast the camera follows this path?

Answer (score 13):

For the object add a **Follow Path constraint** and select the curve you want the object to follow as target. Enable Follow Curve and Enable Animate path.

[image]

Your object will follow that path:

[image]

Add a second curve.

Place your camera at the same in the same origin point of your second curve (the you want to use as travel path) and add a Follow path constraint with the curve as target, and animate path enabled:

[image]

Your camera will travel on that path.

[image]

On the camera add a **Track to** constraint with the object as Target, To -Z and Up Y.

[image]

[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by using additional empty objects.

1. Create a Path
2. Create an empty Cube
3. Set the Cube as parent object for the Camera: select the Camera and Cube and then <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> "Object"
4. Add object constraint for the Cube by right sidebar "Follow Path"

[image]

5. Add am empty Sphere
6. Add object constraint for the Sphere by right sidebar "Follow Path" (Optional)
7. Add object constraint for the Camera "Track to" and select the Sphere (I called it "Camera target"). Also, you must need to use `Target Z`

[image]

Result: you can animate the camera rotation by `Y` use the Sphere `X` and `Z` by the Cube

[image]

[image]

It's an example of how it looks like:

[image]

Blender: 2.8

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just take the camera and put it at the end of curved path then selected both camera and path using <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.

Once selected press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and select follow path. When you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the camera will follow path. The issue is its not following the path, so you do a similar thing to what we did before but you add an empty only this time you place it slightly inside of the path.

Where in this instance the camera is at path end and the empty is slightly to inside the path but near camera. So you select empty and path and click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then follow path. Before you do this make sure timeline is at Zero which places Camera in original position and ensures the empty starts animation from zero.

Once done click on camera then and object constraint called *Track to* then set the target to empty, set values like *Up* to *Y* and to, to *-Z*

Press <kbd>Space</kbd> and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just clamp the camera to the path then create an empty and clamp it to the path as well and parent the empty to the camera, animate the camera location and the empty will follow, then add track to constraint to the camera and select the empty