# How do I add a camera so that it moves along a path while focusing on an object with Python?

Tags: python, scripting, camera, path

How do I add a camera and script it so that it moves along a path *while* focusing on one object? 
I would also like to know how to have it rotating around the origin where one of the main objects of interest sits.

Comment: Hundreds of options, I think [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46898/31447) is the way to go...

Comment: HI. Are you specifically wanting to do this as a script or did you just mention that because you think it's a possible solution?

Comment: Yes specifically as a script. But thank you for the link anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basic example using a circle based on [Cegaton's setup from here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46898/31447).

[image]

Add the primitives and a camera. Assign each object reference to a new variable and add a *Follow Path* and *Track To* constraint using [`Object.constraints.new()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectConstraints.html?highlight=constraints%20new#bpy.types.ObjectConstraints.new) method. Finally set all the constraint properties, eg. assign the variables to the [`FollowPath.target`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FollowPathConstraint.html?highlight=target#bpy.types.FollowPathConstraint.target) or set [`TrackTo.up_axis`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.TrackToConstraint.html?highlight=up_axis#bpy.types.TrackToConstraint.up_axis) to `'UP_Y'`:

```
import bpy

# Add Suzanne
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add(size=2)
suzanne = bpy.context.object

# Add Circle
bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(radius=10)
circle = bpy.context.object

# Add Camera
bpy.ops.object.camera_add(location=(0, 0, 0))
camera = bpy.context.object

# Follow Path Constraint
fp_constraint = camera.constraints.new('FOLLOW_PATH')
fp_constraint.target = circle

# Animate Button
bpy.ops.constraint.followpath_path_animate({
    'constraint':camera.constraints["Follow Path"]
    }, constraint='Follow Path')

# Track-To Constraint
tt_constraint = camera.constraints.new('TRACK_TO')
tt_constraint.target = suzanne
tt_constraint.up_axis = 'UP_Y'
tt_constraint.track_axis = 'TRACK_NEGATIVE_Z'
```