# How do I set up a Follow Path constraint and also control its influence?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, constraints

I need to add a [*Follow Path* constraint](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/follow_path.html) to an object and also set up key frames to turn off the influence of that constraint after one rotation around the path: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.FollowPathConstraint.html#bpy.types.FollowPathConstraint

I found an influence adjustment [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Constraint.html) but I can't seem to even get the constraint working in the first place. Some guidance on this issue would help my overall understanding of the Docs.

Comment: Examples in  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/168913/how-do-i-add-a-camera-so-that-it-moves-along-a-path-while-focusing-on-an-object/168948#168948  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118290/continuous-looping-animation-differing-rotational-speeds   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91455/i-am-trying-to-make-an-animation-of-a-double-planet-cant-seem-to-get-it-right   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/176762/15543

Comment: Thank you these are helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code worked for me:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.object
curve_ob = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]


con = ob.constraints.new('FOLLOW_PATH')
con.target = curve_ob

curve_ob.data.use_path = True
anim = curve_ob.data.animation_data_create()
anim.action = bpy.data.actions.new("%sAction" % curve_ob.data.name)

fcu = anim.action.fcurves.new("eval_time")
mod = fcu.modifiers.new('GENERATOR')
mod.use_restricted_range = True 

mod.frame_start = 1
mod.frame_end = 100
```