# Is it possible to transform an armature into a curve?

Tags: armature, camera, bezier-curves

I have a tunnel that I want a camera to go through, and want to replace the armature with a curve so it moves exactly on that path. I'd like the camera to also rotate to follow the bends of the tunnel. Using cycles.

Appreciate it, the problem I'm having now is that the camera follows the path, but after each turn, kind of snaps back or bumps, like a recoil of sorts. I reduced the size of the turns, but it still happens. And within the graph editor I can't change the interpolation mode, it's all greyed out. The only reason it looks kind of decent is because the camera is set to 15mm. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: sometimes it's jerky because the curve's resolution is not high enough but it doesn't seem to be the case here... maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make the armature match the position of a bezier curve with a spline IK constraint.  Setting it up is a lot like making an IK constraint but with a couple extra steps.

1) Setup your bones.  It looks like you have done that already, though be warned: since it is an IK constraint it works from the tip of the hierarchy towards the Root, not the other way around.

2) Add a bezier curve and add the number of control points you want in the form of edge vertices.

3) Add some control objects for the curve.  Many people just add some empties for this purpose, but there is nothing stopping you from just making armature bones.  However: *it is not a good idea to use bones from the Armature that is being controlled by the Spline IK, as it will likely create a cyclical dependency.*

4) Hook those vertices of the curve to the control objects. (go into the curve's edit mode, click a vertex, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, choose appropriate option).

5) Apply the Spline IK constraint to the last bone of the chain.  Configure "Chain Length" to match the number of bones in the curvy part of the armature.  Play with the other settings as you see fit.

When done, you should be left with a curvy poseable armature controlled with your control objects.  You can mess with the control handles of the curve by rotating and scaling your control objects.

[image: Successful bezier rig demo]

The rig shown here is a bit more complicated, since I did want bones to control how this armature worked.  It involves creating two armatures, one parented to another, and the top level armature controls everything (including the Bezier curve).

Comment: This saved me, thanks! I got the camera following the path created by the armature now. How do I get the camera to rotate and move with the tunnel? Right now I'm using the "follow path" constraint on the camera

Comment: This question here has a few options you might want to try: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46888/camera-follow-path-and-change-rotation.  -- If you found this answer helpful feel free to mark it as the solution

Comment: Appreciate it, the problem I'm having now is that the camera follows the path, but after each turn, kind of snaps back, like a recoil of sorts. I reduced the size of the turns, but it still happens. And within the graph editor I can't change the interpolation mode, it's all greyed out. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably will need to ask a new question for that