# Constricting the camera animation to the inside of the wormhole

Tags: animation, camera

I just currently finished doing Gleb Alexandrov and Aidy Burrow's space VFX Elements course (the wormhole tutorial in particular) and had a question about camera animation. Does anyone know how I would be able to constrict the camera to the inside of the wormhole and to make the camera eventually fly out through the end of the wormhole? I'm having difficulty figuring this out so any tips/input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if the tunnel is made with a curve, the camera could follow the curve with a Follow Path constraint?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177314/is-it-possible-to-transform-an-armature-into-a-curve?